# Problems if i will visit another person different from my visa application?

Tags: visas

I'm venezuelan and i have a tourist visa for 6 months. When I apply for the tourist visa, I sent the info of the person who i was going to visit. I couldn't go because I decided to start a coach training and he moved to the Netherlands. Now I have a relationship with a british citizen and i want to visit him, there's a problem for that? i will visit and stay with a person different from my aplication visa...

Comment: For clarity, which country do you have a tourist visa for and when was it granted?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem. The visa was issued based on the information you gave and now your situation has changed.

Because of that, you may be refused entry to the UK even though you have the visa.

However, this would be a decision to be made by the immigration staff based on all the information available to them. Therefore it is hard to predict what will happen.

Comment: @Caterina Change of circumstances and their possible effect is covered under v9.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules It would be wise to contact the embassy that issued the visa to clarify prior to travel, in order to avoid problems during your landing interview. You should also be aware that the standard UK visa duration is 6 months, but the actual length of time you spend in the UK should be as stated in your application.